# How to make Prediction with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am new to python and ML. Currently trying to use Keras I get import error when trying to import `decode_predictions` and  `preprocess_input`.  More so when trying to use `get_default_graph` for `inception_model` I get `Attribute Error`. Everything  seems to be working in the video tutorial am using.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from keras.applications import inception_resnet_v2 as InceptionResNetV2,decode_predictions, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from IPython.core.display import display
```

```
inception_model.graph= tf.get_default_graph()
```

Comment: Hello @Hoc and welcome to SO. Please provide the code of `inception_model` initialization in order to make this case reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the import, use the following command:

```py
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import (decode_predictions,
                                                    preprocess_input,
                                                    InceptionResNetV2)
```